# How long does the blockers effect last?

Tags: sense8

Sensates can use "blockers" (pills) to prevent other sensates from reaching them. I wonder how long the effect approximately lasts, is it one hour, one day, more ? Do they mention it in the show ?

( I know some sensates make their own blockers, so let's just talk about BPO's blockers )